# wait for mysql to come online, do commands, and shut it down gracefully in bash

Tags: mysql, bash

I'm working on a bash script that turns mysql on, performs some actions and than shuts it down.

I'm afraid that `/usr/bin/mysqladmin ping -h 127.0.0.1 --silent` is not a safe way to go about it. How do I make sure that mysql is ON or OFF so I can proceed?

p.s. this is docker container, so I don't have `service`.

```
if [[ ! -f /var/lib/mysql/status.secured ]]; then
  echo "Starting MariaDB... to secure it!"
  /usr/bin/mysqld_safe
  while ! /usr/bin/mysqladmin ping -h 127.0.0.1 --silent; do
    sleep 1
  done
  mysqladmin -u root password "$DATABASE_PASS"
  mysql -u root -p"$DATABASE_PASS" -e "UPDATE mysql.user SET Password=PASSWORD('$DATABASE_PASS') WHERE User='root'"
  mysql -u root -p"$DATABASE_PASS" -e "DELETE FROM mysql.user WHERE User='root' AND Host NOT IN ('localhost', '127.0.0.1', '::1')"
  mysql -u root -p"$DATABASE_PASS" -e "DELETE FROM mysql.user WHERE User=''"
  mysql -u root -p"$DATABASE_PASS" -e "DELETE FROM mysql.db WHERE Db='test' OR Db='test\_%'"
  mysql -u root -p"$DATABASE_PASS" -e "FLUSH PRIVILEGES"
  touch /var/lib/mysql/status.secured
  mysqladmin -u root -p"$DATABASE_PASS" -h 127.0.0.1 --protocol=tcp shutdown
  while /usr/bin/mysqladmin ping -h 127.0.0.1 --silent; do
    sleep 1
  done
fi
```

I'm specially worried for shutdown part, maybe its better to check if `PID` exists? or `grep` `ps aux` ?

Comment: you could communicate using signals, see https://medium.com/@gchudnov/trapping-signals-in-docker-containers-7a57fdda7d86#.g3ualuhyk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can suggest two options to try:

Use `mysqladmin` and check the exit status

```
mysqladmin -h server_ip -u username -p passsword processlist
if [ $? -ne 0 ] then; ... system down
```

Use `grep` and check for process `mysql`

```
STATUS=$(grep mysql | wc -l);
if [ "STATUS" -ne 1 ] then; ... system down
```

Comment: what about checking if its up? ping can be misleading right? docs say it can say up if connection fails.

Comment: `ping` just tells you that you can reach the server.  `mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed` will be the response if MySQL is down.  You can use either option above to check the status from the previous command.  I have updated the first answer to show that status check.